# Why is the text next to the Facebook buttons split in 2 lines?

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-like

any idea why the text next to the Facebook buttons is split into 2 lines? Would expect only one line since the width of the red DIV allows it. Thanks

[image]
HTML

```
<div id="footer" class="top">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.google.be" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
      <!-- End fblike  --></div>
    <div class="right">&copy; 2013 ddss.com. Tous droits réservés.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
#footer {  
    position: relative;  
    left: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    height: 26px;  
    width: 100%;  
    background: #fff; 
    border-top: 5px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: thin;
    border-top-color: #124191; 
    padding-top: 8px;
}  


#footer .left {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 3px;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: red;
    width:60%;
}
#footer .right {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: green;
    width:37%;
}
```

Comment: looks all right to me, might be something else, try add white-space: nowrap to your #footer .left

Comment: Thanks. Just tried. Without success unfortunately

Comment: do you have a live demo so that I can debug for you?

Comment: Sure, there you go http://goo.gl/F8ciEs Note that in english it might be OK since the text is shorter. thanks

Comment: just had a quick look at your code, it's sooooooo NESTED! do you really need to wrap your content with so many nested tags? elements inside elements? just for a single footer? if this is what you want and you are happy with it, to fix your problem, search your code and look for value 450px, the table and span in your left foot are restricted with this width that's why your words wrapped.

Comment: Looks like Facebook iframe's width by default is 450px, will try to find a way to change that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add data-width 100% to the fb-like class, like this:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-width="100%" data-href="https://www.google.be" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! 100% doesn't work but a fixed width of 550px did the trick! thanks